# Calling web service and XML Parser from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I have to hit many web services in same class and from another classes also and I have to parse the data each time.I cant write the delegate methods for webservice hit and XML Parse everytime as its not a good programming practice. So I thought of maintaining common classes for 'webserviceHandler' and 'XMLParsingHandler' in which I will write delegate methods for web service and XMLParsing respectively.
Now the problem is how to make it happen to call these delegates each and everytime I hit the webservice from another classes..??
Code for this is more appreciable..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

[Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) Chapter 28. Web Services using NSXMLDocument

There is also an example from ADC [SeismicXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html) using NSXMLParser

Comment: Plz provide me the link for that